# Left/Inner join with AND,WHERE, and OR

Tags: php, sql, join

I have 2 tables:

Friends

```
  ID  |  Profile  |  Check
------+-----------+---------
  int |    int    |   bool
```

Where `ID` is person who sent original friend request, `Profile` is ID of person request was sent to, and `Check` is 0 = request pending; 1 = request accepted.

Messages

```
  OwnerID  |  ...
-----------+-------
    int    |  ...
```

Where `OwnerID` is ID of member who wrote the message.

So basically, what I am looking at is first:

select all rows from friends_list table where ID or Profile is equal to the memberID cookie. BUT heres my plight: If I send another user a friend request, then my ID is placed in the ID field and their ID is placed in the Profile field of the friend_list table. But if another user requests a friend request from me, then my ID would go into the Profile field and theirs would go in the ID field.

So, I would have a row where ID = 1, and Profile = 2. And the next row would be ID = 3 and Profile = 1. Now, both users with IDs 2 and 3 are friends of mine (ID 1), So I need to show all messages from 1, 2, and 3 (mine and my two friends) where check = 1

Comment: SELECT * FROM Messages,Friends WHERE 'YOURCOOKIEID' IN(`ID`, `Profile` )

Answer (score 1):

I *think* what you want is this:

```sql
(
    SELECT m.*
    FROM Messages m
    INNER JOIN Friends f ON m.OwnerID = f.ID
    WHERE f.Profile = ?
) UNION (
    SELECT m.*
    FROM Messages m
    INNER JOIN Friends f ON m.OwnerID = f.Profile
    WHERE f.ID = ?
)
```

You need to look at this a two separate queries, I don't think you can sensibly do this with *just* a combination of `JOIN`s.

Assuming you are using MySQL, this should not return duplicate rows, because the default modifier for `UNION` is `DISTINCT`. Other RDBMS engines may require you to explicitly state this or use some other work-around (for example a `GROUP BY` on the actual message ID).

You may also want to add an `m.Check = 1` condition to the `WHERE` clause of both queries, to ensure you only get messages where the friend request has been accepted.

Obviously the above is designed to be used as a prepared statement, where both placeholders would be substituted with the same data - the `memberID` cookie.

Comment: OK,I played around with this for a day, and I sort of got it to work. At least on my site it does, but when applying to a friends site, it doesnt. Is there a way to use an OR in an inner join?  What I mean is - I have:    INNER JOIN `messages` AS `p` ON `p`.`OwnerID` = `f`.`ID` ORDER BY `p`.`ID` what I want is: